# How do I use a melee weapon on a motorcycle?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

In GTA Online, how do I use a melee weapon (such as a hatchet or nightstick) on a motorcycle? It is in the weapon list but standard controls don't seem to work. Please provide both keyboard+mouse and controller controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I have been reading in order to use melee weapons on a bike you have to hold X (or A if you are on Xbox) and hit L1 or R1 (LB or RB on Xbox) to select which side you swing on. There is less info on the PC but it sounds like it is holding x on the keyboard and left and right click to decide which side so swing on.